# Remove HTML Encoded characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-encode

I'm getting some data from the database and it has HTML Encoded chars (`&nbsp;`).  What options are there for removing these?

I don't want these rendered at all...I want them stripped from the data.

At the moment I'm not worried about the HTML tags...just the encoded characters.

EDIT: If it's relevant these chars are causing some errors in JSON validation.

Comment: Can you prevent them from going in, in the first place?

Comment: How are you outputting the JSON?  It seems to me like a JSON library should be able to easily handle the encoding/decoding of HTML encoded characters.

Comment: @ErikPhilips not really they are needed in certain places, but in a datatable.net table they are causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of them, obtain a list of such characters or a RegExp matching them all (something like `&[a-z]+;`) and do a search-and replace.

However, if you only want them gone due to errors in JSON validation, you should correctly generated/encode your JSON to avoid the errors. (However, I don't really understand how they can cause invalid JSON.)

Comment: Whenever it's getting encoded/used by `datatables.net` it's causing the validation issue (I believe).  *Parse error on line 8:
...ado",            ""BeginAllYourAdventur
----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'*

Comment: Somehow, a quote character `"` got in there, ending the string and messing up the JSON. `&` and `;` have no special meaning in JSON, `"` does. I'd suggest you create a minimal example demonstrating the full issue (including the generated JSON), as I believe it does not have much to do with HTML entities in general.

Answer (score 0):

Simply trimming by regexp should not be an option here. For example `&nbsp;` can be coded as `&#160;` as well, but `&\#[0-9]+;` regex would lead to data loss, since almost every char can become encoded like that at some point
(ex.:`<p>&#72;&#69;&#76;&#76;&#79;</p>`).